# Distributed android app not available on any devices

Tags: android, google-play

I recently distributed my first app to the android play store. 
In the developers console it shows that 6162 devices are supported and none are excluded, also  If I copy the .apk to any of my devices It runs perfectly fine. But when I open the app in play.google.com It says that none of my devices are supported so I can't install it, although in the developers console all my devices are supported. I have no idea at all why this problem is occurring so any hint or tip would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.luttikdevelopment.vegimmanuel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name="com.luttikdevelopment.vegimmanuel.VEG_Immanuel"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.luttikdevelopment.vegimmanuel.Agenda"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.luttikdevelopment.vegimmanuel.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.luttikdevelopment.vegimmanuel.AgendaItemView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda_item_view" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.luttikdevelopment.vegimmanuel.AgendaSettings"
            android:label="Instellingen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This may be caused by some specifications in your manifest file. Can you post it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231444/this-app-is-not-compatible-with-your-device-error-in-the-google-play-store

Comment: I've added the manifest but I don't think that that is the problem here.