# My device is in compatible devices list on Play Developer Console, but it doesn't allow me to download it

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app and I have 5940 compatible devices (when I check it on Developers Console), but none of them looks compatible when I get the link to download it. I just use the Internet permission and the app is very simple.

[Here is the link of the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.helptaxi)

What could it be? I have the screens small, normal, large and xlarge and everything looks fine.

Comment: Plz post your Manifest file

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232457/distributed-android-app-not-available-on-any-devices#comment37423803_24232457 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730560/the-app-is-incompatible-with-all-your-devices

Comment: Sorry, it looks the client who uploaded the app was making some changes on his account (like username). I think that's why it wasn't working, because now it's working with the same apk.